# Getting an IndexError when trying to run a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: index-error

I have a dataframe consisting of data I got from Alpaca API.

```
# Set the ticker
ticker = "TSLA"

# Set timeframe to '1D'
timeframe = "1D"

# Set start and end datetimes of 3 years from Today
start_date = pd.Timestamp("2020-04-21", tz="America/New_York").isoformat()
end_date = pd.Timestamp("2023-04-21", tz="America/New_York").isoformat()

# Get 3 years worth of historical data for TSLA
ticker_data = alpaca.get_bars(
    ticker,
    timeframe,
    start=start_date,
    end=end_date,
    limit=1000
).df
```

The following is the Output:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRbhn.png)

Then when I try to start a Monte Carlo Simulation for 3 years

```
# Configure a Monte Carlo simulation to forecast three years daily returns
MC_threeyears = MCSimulation(
    portfolio_data=ticker_data,
    weights=[1],
    num_simulation=1000,
    num_trading_days=252*3
)
```

I get an **IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2**
The index of the ticker_data dataframe is in DateTimeIndex

Any idea on how to fix this?

I've used the exact same MCSimulation parameters in another notebook with another dataframe that holds multiple stocks and I wasn't getting any issues.